# How to change YouTube channel URL back to username?

Tags: youtube

How do I change the channel link back to http://youtube.com/user/myusername from http://youtube.com/channel/stringOfCharacters ?

I don't see anything in the settings that will allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a way to set custom URL to your channel.  But once you do this it will be permanent and you cannot change it back to your old user name.

Find more at https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968?hl=en

Comment: That linked page doesn't say (or perhaps no longer says) chosen URLs are permanent.